# jQuery "find" method alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.wrapper a').find('a'); //return empty object
```

But i am looking for a way get all anchors by selector. Problem is find method look at only descendants so what is alternative of it ?

Please test it on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/sbbah/)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to select?

Comment: It is quite spesific to tell it. I have simply $('.wrapper .spesific') object and i want to query .spesific elements which is inside that object.

Comment: You already have them with the selector `$('.wrapper .spesific')`. From your jsFiddle example, what do you want the `var div` to hold?

Comment: @Shef - This is only example. If a method gets an object which is $('.wrapper .spesific') so i want to get .spesific for filtering in that object. filter method is right method.

Comment: Okay, this has been resolved then by my answer and @ShankarSangoli's one.

Comment: what you are asking is unclear to me. do you want to know how to select a specific element, all anchor elements, or all anchor elements with child anchors?

Comment: I want to be able to write a new selector which is able to query in anchor elements which is not descendants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery `find` gets the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

`children` gets the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

I think you are trying to find the elements at the same level then you should use `children`. Alternatively you can also use `filter` to filter the matched results based on selector.

`filter` reduces the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Try this

```
var div = $('.wrapper div').filter('.parent');
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking for this?

```
var div = $('.wrapper div').filter('.parent');
```

[**A forked demo of yours**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/sUgwR/)

Answer (score 2):

the alternatives of `.find()` function which are as below:

1. [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) it selects only **first-level descendants** or direct child elements. for example `$('#parent_id > #child_id')` or `$(".parent > .first-level-child")`
2. [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) it selects a **child, grandchild, great-grandchild**, and so on, of that element. in it you can use `$('#parent_id #child_id')` or `$('#parent_id #grandchild_id')` or `$(".parent .great-grand-child")` or `$( "form input" )`
3. [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)  only search in those **elements that match the precondition**.
4. [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) get the **parent of each element in the current set** of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.
5. [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) it works exactly the same way as find, but it will only find **first-level-children**, not more distant descendants.
6. [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)  get the **closest (first) element** that matches the selector, starting at the current element.

for detailed info about jquery selectors check [JQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

`$('.wrapper a').find('a');` find links inside links that are descendants of .wapprer.
I think you might have meant `$('.wrapper').find('a');`. In your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbbah/1/) that would be

```
$('.wrapper').find('.parent');`
```

insetead of:

```
$('.wrapper div').find('.parent');
```