# jquery .find() function alternative?

Tags: jquery, performance, find

`.find()` functions runs very slow in IE 7 and below, frequently resulting in hang ups.

Could someone suggest me an alternative?

Here is the code snippet.

```
$(".dobAutoTab").each(function() { 
    var dobFields = $(this).children().find("input"); 
    var fldDate = $(dobFields[0]); 
    var fldMonth = $(dobFields[1]); 
    var fldYear = $(dobFields[2]); 
)};
```

Comment: possible dupicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258829/jquery-find-method-alternative

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate; that question is about behavior, while this one is about performance.

Comment: The performance of `.find` will vary wildly per browser per selector. Give us some examples of the selectors you are using and we may be able to help you choose better ones. Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Anyway - we'll need to see some specific code. It depends on what exactly it is you're trying to find. IE7 is slow, but it can be made to perform OK.  Without seeing your code however nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Here is the code snippet.

$(".dobAutoTab").each(function() {
                var dobFields = $(this).children().find("input");
                var fldDate = $(dobFields[0]);
                var fldMonth = $(dobFields[1]);
                var fldYear = $(dobFields[2]);
)};

Answer (score 8):

Mostly it depends on what you are trying to achieve:

- [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) only search in those elements that match the precondition.
- [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) search under children, children's children, and all descendants.
- [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) works exactly the same way, but will only find children, not more distant descendants.
- [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) get the closer (first) element that matches the selector, starting at the current element.
- [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Of course the more specific your selector is, the faster your results will be.

And, if you can, search what you need inside contexts, that way would be even faster, for more info about selectors, [check here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 3):

Try using normal CSS selectors, `$('#id span')` for example basically is `$('#id').find('span')` but much much faster.

But anyway, some code examples would get you a more specific answer.

Comment: Here is the code snippet. 
$(".dobAutoTab").each(function(){ var dobFields = $(this).children().find("input"); var fldDate = $(dobFields[0]); var fldMonth = $(dobFields[1]); var fldYear = $(dobFields[2]); )};

Comment: You'd best post not just your JS but also your HTML structure in your question. Maybe your current approach isn't very effective/clean in doing what you want anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As Luis said `.filter(), .children(), .closest() and parent()` functions can be used for alternative to `.find()` function i want to add two more selector from jquery selector to the alternative of `.find()` function which are as below:

1. [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) it selects only **first-level descendants** or direct child elements. for example `$('#parent_id > #child_id')` or `$(".parent > .first-level-child")`
2. [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) it selects a **child, grandchild, great-grandchild**, and so on, of that element. in it you can use `$('#parent_id #child_id')` or `$('#parent_id #grandchild_id')` or `$(".parent .great-grand-child")` or `$( "form input" )`